# How to determine/change install state of a Wix Bundle programatically?

Tags: c#, wix, burn, dtf

I have a Wix Managed Bootstrapper Application / bundle (burn) installer.

From C#, I need to determine the install state of that bundle using either the ProductCode or UpgradeCode of the bundle.  I attempted to use the Wix Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) library's `Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.ProductInstallation` class, but it does not appear to work for bundles, just the embedded packages (MSIs):

```
var myBundle = new ProductInstallation(bundleProductCode);
if (myBundle.IsInstalled) ... // This returns false, even if the bundle is installed
```

I eventually also need to attempt to uninstall the bundle from the same code. I planned to use the DTF's `Installer.ConfigureProduct` static method, but it also appears to not work with bundles, only products, as the following call throws an `ArgumentException` with the message "This action is only valid for products that are currently installed." even though the bundle is installed:

```
Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Installer.ConfigureProduct(
      bundleProductCode, 0, InstallState.Absent, "");
```

So, my question is:

**How can I determine the current install state for my bundle and how can I force an uninstall, all from C# (preferably using the DTF API)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bundles are a layer above MSI, so MSI has no knowledge of them and can't operate on them. [WiX v3.9](http://wixtoolset.org/releases/) has functions in the C/C++ DUtil library to get bundle information, including the path to the cached bundle to uninstall or repair it. So far, nobody's done the work to translate that to C#.

Comment: Is there a (rough) ETA for v3.9 release?

Comment: Still being discussed but we're currently ballparking v3.9 for summer.

Comment: Any update on this? Has anyone done some work on this?